# Convert sybase string column into SAS Date

Tags: date, sas

I'm trying to convert a string column which is in sybase in the below format into SAS date.

The sybase table has string values like this

```
2015-04-23 04:04:46.517
2015-04-22 04:04:35.162
2015-04-21 04:04:43.646
```

I need to get the max of these values and store it in a `max_tmsp` variable and get the records where `last_updt_tmsp > max_tmsp`.

I referred to this [link](http://studysas.blogspot.ca/2010/09/how-to-convert-character-string-date-to.html) and tried to write some code but it is not working.

All this code is in Precode before the job starts.

```
proc sql noprint;

SELECT

select max(input(PROPERTY_VAL, MDYAMPMw.d)) into :last_updt_tmsp

from sybase_lib.prop_vals  where property_key='last.update.date';

quit;

format &last_updt_tmsp. DATETIME18.;

data _null_;

call symput('lst_cre_dttm',"'"||"&last_updt_tmsp."||"'dt");

run;

%put lst_cre_dttm=&lst_cre_dttm
```

Comment: "But it is not working" isn't particularly helpful. What happens when you use that code?

Comment: Also the code you've posted doesn't make sense. `format` statements aren't valid in open code, and you have `select` twice in a row in your SQL step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together answer and comment about the answer

```
Data HAVE;
length PROPERTY_VAL $23;
Input PROPERTY_VAL $ 1-23;
Datalines;
2015-04-23 04:04:46.517
2015-04-22 04:04:35.162
2015-04-21 04:04:43.646
;
Run;

proc sql noprint;
select max(input(PROPERTY_VAL, anydtdtm24.)),
      max(input(PROPERTY_VAL, anydtdtm24.)) format=datetime22.3
into :last_updt_tmsp, :last_updt_tmsp_f
from HAVE;
quit;

%Put LAST_UPDT_TMSP: &last_updt_tmsp (&last_updt_tmsp_f);
```

Comment: DCR and Carolina thank you very much. 

Also is it possible to see what value is store in &last_updt_tmsp in the log 

 I took carolina explanation though i'm sure DCR yours works too .. I did not must change the bottom part

proc sql noprint;

SELECT

select max(input(PROPERTY_VAL, anydtdtm24.)) format=datetime22.3 into :last_updt_tmsp
from sybase_lib.prop_vals  where property_key='last.update.date';

quit;

format &last_updt_tmsp. DATETIME18.;

data _null_;

call symput('lst_cre_dttm',"'"||"&last_updt_tmsp."||"'dt");

run;

%put lst_cre_dttm=&lst_cre_dttm

Answer (score 3):

you can do this in a data step, try the following:

```
data datetime;
format new_date datetime24.3;
a="2015-04-23 04:04:46.517";
new_date=input(a, anydtdtm24.);
run;
```

Using proc  sql you can try:

```
proc sql;
select max(input(a,anydtdtm24.)) format datetime24.3 into: max_date
from table1;
quit;

%put &max_date;
```

the point to remember is max of a character variable will not give you consistent results as compared to max of a numeric variable.  You want the latter.

Comment: DCR sorry am new to sas, How do I read the column and store it in that variable from table like select max(preoperty_val) into :new_DATE FROM TABLE PROPERTY

Answer (score 0):

DCR and Carolina thank you very much. It worked. Can you please tell me the difference between max(input(PROPERTY_VAL, anydtdtm24.)) format=datetime22.3 and max(input(a,anydtdtm24.)) format datetime24.3 .

DCR i will keep your point in mind and let my team know and see if we can switch to the last_updt_dt column

Also is it possible to see what value is stored in &last_updt_tmsp in the log

I took carolina explanation though i'm sure DCR yours works too .. I did not  change the bottom part

proc sql noprint;

SELECT

select max(input(PROPERTY_VAL, anydtdtm24.)) format=datetime22.3 into :last_updt_tmsp
from sybase_lib.prop_vals  where property_key='last.update.date';

quit;

format &last_updt_tmsp. DATETIME18.;

data *null*;

call symput('lst_cre_dttm',"'"||"&last_updt_tmsp."||"'dt");

run;

%put lst_cre_dttm=&lst_cre_dttm